# GWT locale property - new language for users needs more compilations

Tags: java, gwt, compilation, locale

To set a certain number of preferred languages for users, GWT offers the mapping between the "locale" property (en, ro, fr ...)  and a Constants_xx.properties file. The problem is that when adding a new value to that locale, the compiler executes 6 more compilations. My app currently needs 12 compilations witch are executed in about 7 minutes (for default language and English - en). So if i want to add support for 4 more languages, that will take 36 compilations. 
My question is: the time and processing taken by the compilations executed for the "locale" value will about the same as those executed for the different types of browsers ? So, if 12 compilations take about 7 minutes, will 36 (6 + 30) compilations take about 21 minutes? Or are these compilations less intensive so these (so they will take about 12 minutes let's say)?
After all, it's just about mapping some string properties to some different values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will take about the same time for each permutation. It is doing it because each permutation will be optimized specifically. If you don't like long compilation time you can use [soft permutations](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/SoftPermutations), to merge some permutations or for development purposes you can use -draftCompile + setting locale to some specific values

Answer (score 2):

If your build machine has multiple cores then the compiler option [-localWorkers](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideCompilerOptions) can reduce the compile time drastically. The GWT compiler then starts multiple worker threads to compile the permutations in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

GWT compiles permutations for (browser version X locale).
This may lead to longer compile-times, but will be a speed-boost at runtime, since no more runtime-magic is required for finding the right locale.